# Drawing text across sphere in SceneKit

Tags: ios, text, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I just started out using SceneKit in my UIKit app with the aim of displaying and manipulating some 3D models. I need to show a sphere with some short text written across it. I am rendering the sphere like this:

```
let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -1, y: 0, z: 8)
sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan

self.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

I tried using a `CATextLayer` to achieve what I need but I've had little luck. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap around the sphere?

Comment: @0x141E essentially yes, I need it to be part of the surface of the sphere

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap text around the surface of an object by creating an image containing text, for example,

[image]

and then loading and assigning the image to the diffuse's `contents` property by

```
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

    if let textImage = UIImage(named:"TextImage") {
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = textImage
    }

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can programmatically create an image with text by

```
func imageWithText(text:String, fontSize:CGFloat = 150, fontColor:UIColor = .black, imageSize:CGSize, backgroundColor:UIColor) -> UIImage? {

    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)

    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }

    // Fill the background with a color
    context.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
    context.fill(imageRect)

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    // Define the attributes of the text
    let attributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT", size:fontSize),
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor
    ]

    // Determine the width/height of the text for the attributes
    let textSize = text.size(attributes: attributes)

    // Draw text in the current context
    text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: imageSize.width/2 - textSize.width/2, y: imageSize.height/2 - textSize.height/2), withAttributes: attributes)

    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```

and apply the image to the sphere with

```
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

    if let image = imageWithText(text: "Hello, World!", imageSize: CGSize(width:1024,height:1024), backgroundColor: .cyan) {
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
    }

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Thank you!

Comment: When the attributes of the text to be displayed are specified, is there a way to make it such that it renders the text as HTML? I am doing something similar for UILabel with a custom `setHTML` method that sets the `documentType` attribute.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that would allow you to do that. Perhaps you can accomplish the same or something similar with an `NSAttributedString`.